# Android: How can I remove the title bar without removing splitactionbar at the bottom?

Tags: java, android, css

Yeah pretty much the title. I tried different android styles, but I lose both the title and the action bar at the bottom. I also tried using

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

But with this I get a blank title bar. I want to remove the title bar completely. Does anyone know a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the fading actionbar example, see if you can tweak it to hide the top bar http://www.androidviews.net/2013/05/fading-actionbar/

Comment: wow! that looks awesome, gonna bookmark that site for the future. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: It is pretty much

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
        <item name="android:height">0dip</item>
    </style>
```

I just sized it to zero and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Theme.Holo.Light and want to use the Theme.Holo.Light.NoTitleBarBar variant on pre 3.2 devices you can add this to your styles.xml:

```
<style name="NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar" ... />
```

Comment: It does not remove the title bar :/ I'm using 4.0+

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate do this

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: I still lose the action bar at the bottom ):

Comment: try this for showing the action bar after your title bar is hidden.

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide(); // slides out
actionBar.show(); // slides in

Comment: That is very interesting! If I use the the actionBar.hide() followed by actionBar.show() - I got to see only the TitleBar without the ActionBar at the bottom. But if I use the requestWindowFeature(...) it will crash. Seems like we are getting closer :)

Comment: Do u have an actionbar in your activity because Actionbar bar = getActionBar() will return you the action bar ofthat activity and null if it doesnt have one.that is why your app is crashing with nullpointer exception

Comment: The app crashed because if you remove the TitleBar you also remove the ActionBar. These two items are combined. However I found a different solution, see my Edit. Thanks for helping tho.